# Necesito una función que al llamarla, ejecute una determina acción, espere un tiempo determinado y luego hago otra

Tags: javascript

soy un novato en todo esto de la programación Web y en la programación en General tampoco tengo mucha experiencia, así que disculpad mi ignorancia.
Necesito una forma de hacer una función en javascript que haga algo como lo que describo de forma informal en las siguientes lineas:

function x{
  acción a;
  esperar 3 segundos;
  acción b;
}

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cambia los comentarios para tu logica de tu programa

```
var funcionEjemplo=function(){
    //hacer algo 1 
    setTimeout(function(){
    //hacer algo 2
    },2000);
    //hacer algo 3
}
```

Nota: la funcion setTimeout significa que `//hacer algo 2,` demorara 3 segundos en ejecutarlo

> la funcion se llama funcionEjemplo
>
> para invocarlo tendras que hacer de la siguiente manera:
>   `funcionEjemplo();` sip asi de sencillo, tambien puedes trabajar con
>   parametros

te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
var sumarPorPartes=function(a,b,c){
     var suma1=a+b; 
     setTimeout(function(){
     var total=suma1*c;
          console.log(total);
     },3000);
  console.log(suma1);
    }

sumarPorPartes(2,3,4);
```

> todo lo que este dentro del ámbito del cuerpo de la funcion
>   setTimeout() tardara el tiempo que se especifica

Comment: Por favor, podrías escribirlo de otra forma, es que no entiendo como es eso de una variable que recibe a una función, y tampoco se como se llamaría

Comment: @Daniel edite mi respuesta

Comment: Vale, y eso del setTimeout como funciona?

Comment: Disculpe mi ignorancia, y muchas gracias

Comment: Ya lo he probado y funciona perfecto, Mil gracias

Comment: @Daniel edite mi respuesta nuevamente, en el cual demuestro un ejemplo funcional

Comment: Ahora me puede explicar lo del setTimeout.

Comment: Si, si, si se ve la lógica bien, lo que nunca había visto esa forma de llamar a las funciones, jeje

Comment: @Daniel asunto solucionado?

Comment: Si, muchas gracias